# c# interop Word Rotation image

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, image-rotation

I´m trying to rotate an image on my Word Document. But it doesn´t work for me. I don´t know what the problem is. I´m looking for solutions for my problem, but I don´t get it.

I tried to create an image, then rotate it. This is my code, I hope you can help me:

```
private void CargarImagen(Word.Document aDoc, Word.Range rngDoc, byte[] img, RondaParametro param, string text)
{
    Logger.Trace(Logger.GetCallerInfo(), this, "Imprimiendo imagen {0} ", GetParametroIdioma(param));

    object wdSectionBreakNextPage = 2; //el 2 es el tipo. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdbreaktype?view=word-pia

    object lineBreak = 6;
    rngDoc.Select();

    rngDoc.InsertBreak(wdSectionBreakNextPage);

    if (this._ronda.Participaciones.Count() > NumLabImagen)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para = rngDoc.Paragraphs.Add();
        para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

        para.Range.Font.AllCaps = 1;
        para.Range.Text = text;
        para.Range.set_Style(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2);
        para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

        rngDoc.SetRange(para.Range.End, para.Range.End);

        var tmpFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tmpFile, img);

        rngDoc.Select();
        rngDoc.InsertBreak(lineBreak);


        var imag = rngDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(tmpFile, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        Word.Shape shape = imag.ConvertToShape();
        shape.IncrementRotation(90);

        var imagCargada = shape.ConvertToInlineShape();

        rngDoc.SetRange(imagCargada.Range.End, imagCargada.Range.End);            
    }
}
```

I checked `shape.Rotation` and it appears as `0`

[image]

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: hi @NicoHaase i don´t know what i have to check.

Comment: This is not an [mcve] - it's missing important information: there's no indication what the parameters being passed to this function actually contain. This information is required in order to trouble-shoot the behavior. I recommend creating a "text procedure" that contains all the necessary objects, methods and properties for reproducing the behavior, otherwise no one can help you.